# VueJS ignoring global import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, less

I'm trying to import a `.less` file in my `App.vue` so that its contents are available on all components.

I create the example app like this:

`vue create less_test`

then I install the `less` npm packages

```
cd less_test
npm install less less-loader --save-dev
```

I create this simple `less` file in `src/`

*_variables.less*

```
//  Colors
@yellowish: #E19525;
```

Then on *HelloWorld.vue* I change the `<style>` to this:

```
<style lang="less" scoped>
.hello {
  background-color: @yellowish;
}
...
</style>
```

And on *App.vue* to this:

```
<style lang="less">
@import "_variables.less";
...
</style>
```

But when I try to build, I get this error:

```
.hello {
  background-color: @yellowish;
                  ^
Variable @yellowish is undefined
```

How can I import the global `.less` file without having to import it on each component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add a `<style src="@/path/to/_variables.less" lang="scss"></style>` in my App.vue.

Comment: Added `<style src="@/_variables.less" lang="less"></style>` in my *App.vue*, but still have the same issue :/

Comment: Assuming the file path is correct, there must be something else going on -- is it possible it's the `scoped` css in the component? Or maybe it's the preprocessor, does plain css work?

Comment: THought the same and tried a random path which failed, so the path is ok.
Adding that line has no effect at all, even on the component that uses the less file.
Normal css and less works. Importing on the component file also works.
I'm trying this on a barebones app created with vue-cli as per my post, no other modification done :/